# How to use Simple MAPI without mail client?

Tags: c++, service, mfc, mapi, cdo.message

Has a Windows Server 2008 R2 without mail client and not option to install any mail client to this server.

1. I write a service what is use Simple MAPI to get email from exchange server.
2. Already install ExchangeMapiCDO 1.2.1.
3. Use MFCMapi 15 to create a profile and add to profile the Exchange service.

When i start the service drop an error message from MAPI initalization. The message is:

> There is no email program assoxiated to perform the requested action. Please install an email program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.

I need some thing to install to? (Email program is not option) Or i need create/set reg.key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dmitry Streblechenko written below, ExchangeMapiCDO 1.2.1 does not support the Simple MAPI Interface.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all. "install an email program". That is the only option. MAPI is a protocol to talk to email programs. No email program, no MAPI.

Comment: ExchangeMapiCDO 1.2.1 *is* the MAPI system, but I don't think it supports Simple MAPI; only Extended MAPI is supported, and the calling app must dynamically load exmapi32.dll instead of statically linking to the default mapi32.dll in the Windows folder.